# How to parse syslog messages in a syslog4j syslog server

Tags: parsing, syslog, rsyslog, syslog4j

I want to parse syslog messages coming to a syslog server implemented in syslog4J. It is possible to do that in syslog4J?

What I want to do is to be able to segregate out various fields in syslog messages like hostname, timestamp, message, severity level etc. and make a uniform syslog pattern for future analysis.

This king of functionality is available in rsyslog or syslogNG.

```
SyslogServerConfigIF config = new TCPNetSyslogServerConfig("0.0.0.0", 1455);
config.setUseStructuredData(true);

SyslogServerIF syslogserver = SyslogServer.getInstance("tcp");
syslogserver.initialize("tcp", config);
syslogserver.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with creating a new Event Handler class to handle the messages. Note that the parsing should be done in the event() method as that will be called for each syslog event.

```
public class SyslogMessageHandler implements SyslogServerSessionEventHandlerIF {

@Override
public void event(Object session, SyslogServerIF syslogServer, 
                  SocketAddress socketAddress, SyslogServerEventIF event) {
    // Simple parsing for Strings in the message
    if (!event.getMessage().contains(" msg=\"")) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, event.getMessage());
    }

    // You can also build Objects and/or use Pattern/Matcher for parsing.
    MyHTTPLogInfo info = new MyHTTPLogInfo(event.getMessage());
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("^GET\\s+/([^\\s\\?]*)(\\?\\S*)?\\s+HTTP/1\\.\\d$");
    Matcher matcher = myPattern.matcher(info.getHttpRequest());
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, info.getMyCustomLogOutput());
    }
}

@Override
public void exception(Object session, SyslogServerIF syslogServer, SocketAddress socketAddress, Exception exception) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "exception()");
}

@Override
public Object sessionOpened(SyslogServerIF syslogServer, SocketAddress socketAddress) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "sessionOpened()");
    return new Date();
}

@Override
public void sessionClosed(Object session, SyslogServerIF syslogServer, SocketAddress socketAddress, boolean timeout) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "sessionClosed() {0}", session);
}

@Override
public void initialize(SyslogServerIF syslogServer) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "initialize()");
}

@Override
public void destroy(SyslogServerIF syslogServer) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "destroy()");
}
```

Finally register that new class as an EventHandler in the syslog4j config:

`eventHandler = new SyslogMessageHandler();
config.addEventHandler(eventHandler);`

Then you are ready to start testing and debugging your various formats and patterns :)

Comment: can you tell me what packages you need to import to make it work?